# How to formally write "the set of all functions $f: X \rightarrow Y$ satisfying $f(x^*)=y^*$"?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, notation

Let $X$ and $Y$ be arbitrary sets. Then, define the following set:
\begin{gather}
Z=\{f\in Y^X\mid f(x^*)=y^*\}
\end{gather}
Perhaps incorrectly, I read the set $Z$ as the set of all functions $f$ with domain $X$ and codomain $Y$ satisfying the equality $f(x^*)=y^*$. I assumed $Y^X$ to be fairly standard notation to denote the set of all functions with domain $X$ and codomain $Y$, but someone pointed to me that, strictly speaking, the set $Y^X$ is a set of vectors (not a set of functions), thus implying that the set $Z$ is not well-defined.

I need to figure out two things:
(1) Whether my expression above is correct to denote "the set of all functions $f$ from $X$ to $Y$ satisfying $f(x^*)=y^*$";
(2) And if it is not correct, what would be a correct way to denote this set?

Comment: $Y^X$ is fine notation for the set of functions (vectors are functions) but what do $x^{\ast}$ and $y^{\ast}$ mean?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The symbols $x^*$, and $y^*$ just denote some random elements of $X$ and $Y$, respectively.

Comment: How about $Z=\{f : X \to Y \mid f(x^*)=y^*\}$ if the notation $Y^X$ is not common in your field.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. While that's a possibility, I prefer the more compact form of $f\in Y^X$ (assuming it's correct, of course). I believe the compact formulation to be very standard in my field... That's why his comment surprised me and hence this question.

Comment: Is fine. You could add the sentence “where $Y^X$ is the set of all functions from $X$ to $Y$” after defining that.

Comment: I agree with all the other comments.  Another option, particularly if you're using sets like $Z$ frequently, is to abbreviate the entire thing using the language of [pointed sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointed_set):  $Z$ is the set of pointed maps $(X, x^*) \to (Y, y^*)$.

Comment: You stated that $X$ and $Y$ are arbitrary sets. Then $Y^X$ doesn't have a natural vector space structure, so saying "strictly speaking, the set $Y^X$is a set of vectors" is plain wrong. Also, if there were the case of the sets having more structure so that $Y^X$ is in fact a vector space, there's no inherent contradiction: functions can be vectors.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have used and understood the notation correctly.

In a set theoretic context, the notation $Y^X$ being used to denote the set of all functions with domain $X$ and codomain $Y$ is the standard notation. Therefore, the set $Z$ is well defined and your interpretation of the meaning of this set is correct (as long as $f$ is a valid function and $x^*,y^*$ are sets in the domain / codomain of $f$ respectively).

If you are looking for specific classes of functions, then there are alternative choices of notation that you can use. For example, $X \leftrightarrow Y$ is often used to denote the set of bijections from $X$ to $Y$ (although, personally I'm not a fan of this notation as it overloads the $\leftrightarrow$ symbol which typically denotes the the biconditional connective in the context of set theory). The Wikipedia page on [Function Spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_space#) gives a more complete list of examples if you are looking for something more specific (depending on which area of mathematics you are working in), however, in its most general form, this notation is perfectly acceptable.